# Using "Custom Navigation Menus" within a custom theme

Tags: wordpress

I've searched all over and have only found:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
```

I'm not too good with WordPress but I'm guessing this won't be compatible with my current menu. Code below:

```
<li class="mm-item" style="float: left; "> <a href="index-2.html" class="mm-item-link">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a>
  </li>
```

Is there anything capable of outputting that modified per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you can change or add to wp_nav_menu generated code is detailed in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

I'm worried about your code, however, because the link points to index-2.html which is not what it would look like on a Wordpress based system. But perhaps you were just referring to the classes; if so, you can add these through extra parameters.

You should be open to perhaps rewrite your CSS. For example give the menu container an ID and then replace mm-item with #container-id li and mm-item-link with #container-id li a

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what options you are trying to do, you may need to implement a custom walker class. I recently had to do this for a menu intense website that needed heavy customization. Check out this resource, it will get you started: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output (that's if nothing in the function reference from Calle's answer helps you out).